# Java Graphics angle text

Tags: java, string, lwjgl, graphics2d, rotatetransform

what do you do to get a String to be rotated. (but not constantly rotating, just at an angle)?
I tried using `Graphics2D` but couldn't find a method for rotating. or will it require manually rotating it? Also if it's easier I can use LWJGL, but I am not experienced with that library at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a number of ways you might achieve this.

This example simply use an `AffineTransform` to alter the way that the graphics are drawn...

[image: Rotated]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class AngleText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AngleText();
    }

    public AngleText() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            String text = "I don't see the problem";
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getDescent();
            g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(45), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2));
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

For more details, you can take a look at [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, when I ran your code, the string doesn't appear in the same way.  The screenshot is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/7chtk4sb1oz4cmy/string%20rotation.png